# How can a non-expert think of Black Hole microstates?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, string-theory, quantum-gravity, ads-cft

For someone familiar with basic QFT and GR and semi-classical physics but doesn't know string theory nor AdS/CFT is there some intuitive way to think about what the microstate of a black hole means?

Since these are microstates, temperature will not be defined for them. Does their geometry still have a horizon with a finite area? if yes then how is the area-entropy- temperature relationship interpreted in this new conceptual regime?

Do they have singularities or not?

(How) can they be formed? by "collapse"?

Are they classical geometries or inherently quantum in nature? (The ones studied in AdS/CFT would have to be classical since the bulk is in the classical limit right?)

Any intuition apart from the specific questions mentioned would also be appreciated.

(**P.S.** I understand these are a lot of questions and I don't expect all to be answered but asking them separately doesn't seem to make any sense to me either.)

Comment: Well, it would depend on your specific theory of quantum gravity.

Comment: @Javier Could you mention the features in some of the prominent approaches ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the two following excellent references for an intuitive understanding/discussion of the understanding of the black hole entropy whitin string theory.

[Conceptual Analysis of Black Hole Entropy in String Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.03232)

[Emergence and Correspondence for String Theory Black Holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.03234)